# How do I find the smallest value from each group in sql?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

Product:

```
Group_id    Product_id   Size
------------------------------
A             123         s
B             342         xs
A             654         m
A             952         L
B             853         s
B             134         m
```

Size_Code:

```
Size   Size_code
----------------
xs       1
s        2
m        3
L        4
```

I want to find the smallest size product from each product group

Result should look like:

```
Group_id  Product_id  Size
----------------------------
A            123        s
B            342        xs
```

How to write this in SQL? Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `size_code` has the ordering, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.group_id order by s.size_code asc) as seqnum
      from product p join
           size_code s
           on p.size = s.size
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL (no assumptions):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Size_Code s ON s.Size = p.Size
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    p.Group_id,
    min(s.Size_code) as Size_code
  FROM Product p
  INNER JOIN Size_Code s ON s.Size = p.Size
  GROUP BY
    p.Group_id
  ) x on x.Group_id = p.Group_Id AND x.Size_code = s.Size_code
;
```

see:

- [DBFIDDLE MSSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6057a254bbca69c14ce6b37b5e47bf8)
- [DBFIDDLE MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6b5b390cd4cc1f941e89fe54b82f9f1)